# I paste value to textbox by jquery but i can't get this value from behind code

Tags: jquery, asp.net

There are 3 asp:Textbox
Using keyup in jquery to paste value to 3th asp:TextBox from 2 asp:TextBox before.
(asp:Textbox 1 + asp:Textbox 2)

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Total" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

ex:

```
result = parseFloat(txt1) + parseFloat(txt2) 
$('input[id*=Total]').val(result);
```

in view: txt3 is 10

But in behind code I can't get value from 3th asp:TextBox

Comment: does you asp:textbox have runat="server" property?

Comment: Is this resulting value displaying in textbox3?

Comment: in asp:textbox have runnat
yes.textbox3 have value in display

Comment: Is there an attribute 'ViewStateMode' set to 'Disabled' in the third text box?

Comment: yes. disabled textbox

Answer (score 0):

Your asp element should have `runat="server"` so that it can be referenced from code behind.

Note that when you use `runat="server"` the id is auto-generated so you need to specify the `clientIDMode` to make it `static`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Also, if you don't want ClientIDMode to be static you can still reference the asp Element like following:

```
$('#<%=txtBox.ClientID%>').xxx();
```

Comment: Don't successfull

Comment: @user7402860 can you edit the question or paste the whole code in pastebin of your view page and code behind

Comment: Edited. Please view

Comment: @user7402860 can you show more code. How are you trying to get value in the code behind